# ffmpeg, conversion to flv: how to get better quality?

Tags: ffmpeg

**I am using ffmpeg to convert any avi/wmv videos to flv.**

My trouble is that the flv result is quite poor: it gives me big pixelitaed boxes.
I tried to use some -b parameters with no good results:

*ffmpeg -i 1268459654.wmv -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 640x480 x.flv
ffmpeg -i 1268459654.wmv -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 640x480 -b 500k x.f4v*

I also tried 
ffmpeg -i 1268459654.wmv -vcodec libx264  -s 360x240  x.mp4

ans got: *"Unknown encoder 'libx264'"*

Any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libx264 does not come pre-installed (licensing issues I believe) if you've downloaded it via yum/RPM.  You'll need to download the source and compile it yourself and specify libx264.  Here's a command line I've used in the past with decent results, and I would consider the MP4 Container over the dated, FLV format personally.

```
ffmpeg -i (file) -acodec libfaac -ab 44k -vcodec libx264 -vpre normal -crf 30 -threads 0
```

Make note of the "-vpre normal", as you should have some presets available under: 
/usr/share/ffmpeg/libx264-normal.ffpreset or similar.

[More details on compiling from source.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095)